# Did Jesus make 4 promises to the church of Philadelphia?

Tags: greek, revelation, exodus, grammar

A traditional Jewish Passover meal incorporated four cups, one for each of the promises the LORD made before He brought the nation of Israel out of Egypt:

> *Therefore, tell the Israelites, ‘I am the LORD. I will bring you out from your enslavement to the Egyptians, I will rescue you from the hard labor they impose, and I will redeem you with an outstretched arm and with great judgments. I will take you to myself for a people, and I will be your God. Then you will know that I am the LORD your God, who brought you out from your enslavement to the Egyptians. (Exodus 6:6-7 NET)*

In the messages to the seven churches in Asia, the overcomer in each church is given a promise. Those in Philadelphia are told:

> *The one who conquers I will make a pillar in the temple of my God, and he will never depart from it. I will write on him the name of my God and the name of the city of my God (the new Jerusalem that comes down out of heaven from my God), and my new name as well. (Revelation 3:12 NET)*

If Jesus made four separate promises to those in Philadelphia, they would parallel the promises of the Passover tradition:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Does the grammar of the text support seeing the promise as made up of four separate items?

> Ὁ νικῶν ποιήσω αὐτὸν στῦλον ἐν τῷ ναῷ τοῦ θεοῦ μου καὶ ἔξω οὐ μὴ ἐξέλθῃ ἔτι καὶ γράψω ἐπ’ αὐτὸν τὸ ὄνομα τοῦ θεοῦ μου καὶ τὸ ὄνομα τῆς πόλεως τοῦ θεοῦ μου, τῆς καινῆς Ἰερουσαλὴμ ἡ καταβαίνουσα ἐκ τοῦ οὐρανοῦ ἀπὸ τοῦ θεοῦ μου, καὶ τὸ ὄνομά μου τὸ καινόν. (NA28)

Comment: Can you provide the source for Joachim Jeremias' findings?

Comment: Could you give me a link? There doesn't seem to be a wikipedia article on "The Eucharistic Words of Jesus".  There is an article on "Joachim Jeremias", but it doesn't describe his teaching of the four themes. Did he connect these themes to the Quatrodecimans, or was that your connection?

Comment: The "Quartodecimans" were simply those Christians who originally celebrated Easter coincident with the Jewish Passover.  They were not a heretical sect separated from the Church.  The date of Easter did not get resolved until the 1st Ecumenical Council in 325.  Until then, Christians were celebrating Easter over a range of dates.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking if Revelation 3:12 is [alluding to](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allusion) Exodus 6:6,7. According to http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allusion, an allusion contains a [reference](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reference) to another passage:

> Full Definition of allusion 1 :  an implied or indirect reference
>   especially in literature; also :  the use of such references 2 :  the
>   act of making an indirect reference to something :  the act of
>   alluding to something
>
> Simple Definition of reference : the act of mentioning something in
>   speech or in writing : the act of referring to something or someone :
>   the act of looking at or in something for information : a person who
>   can be asked for information about another person's character,
>   abilities, etc.

As I read the Rev. passage I don't see anything that would qualify as a "reference", implied or direct. The form of having four promises is even in doubt.

It seems there is no allusion. In the absence of a reference/allusion the possible similarity of four promises seems extremely remote to the point where I see no reason to imagine they are related at all.

Comment: (-1) You did not answer the question. If John were writing his own thoughts it would be proper to consider what is written as an allusion. However, in this case, both passages record what was spoken by the LORD God and by Jesus. If there is a connection it is because Jesus patterned one after the other, not because the writer interjected something on their own which alluded to the other. Nor do you address the grammar of the passage. Are there four in Revelation?

Comment: There are differences between pattern, allusion, and reference. If you think "pattern" does not apply show your work and explain why the question would be better formed by the concept of "allusion."

Comment: @RevelationLad  So did you just throw in the chart to mess with us?

Comment: No I thought it was a good way to compare them to see if there was a pattern.